# Saving product custom options values to a js file

Tags: javascript, magento

I'm new in magento and i am developing an ecommerce website using magento. I'm using custom options while adding a product , now i just want to save some custom options values(eg: values of color custom option) to a js file while saving / editing the product. where should i add code to do this and how. Does any one have an idea? kindly share it with me.

Comment: If your new to Magento I would suggest reading over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906053/can-someone-recommend-some-magento-tutorials/5914398#5914398

Comment: New means i haven't done so many magento websites. But i know the structure

Comment: what do you mean by "saving to a js file"?

Answer (score 0):

in your config.xml module:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                </yourmodule>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

And in your Observer.php:

```
class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getData()); exit;
        // do something here
    }
}
```

After which you will grab the values you need and write the JS file your needing to build.

Hope this helps.

Source: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/